# Toggle stripe/checkout.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, stripe-payments

How can I toggle the [stripe/checkout.js](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-simple) script after initializing it?

I have a form input field "coupon". If this has a value I would like to bypass the stripe popup/modal and submit right away.

So far I have not managed to unset the event that triggers the stripe functionality. This is the design I have attempted:

```
$('#coupon').bind('input', function(){
    if($('#coupon').val() != "") {
        switchToFreeSubmit()
        return;
    }

    switchToStripeSubmit()
});
```

How can I setup the toggle functions, or are there better ways?

Comment: It depends on our full code really, if you are using the [custom integration of Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom) you would want to put the call to `handler.open` in an if-statement based on the coupon.